# Adjusting lighting in SliceContourPlot3D

Tags: visualization

The following plot is too dark on my screen, but lighting options available for `ListPlot3D` don't see to be available for `SliceContourPlot3D`

```
entropy[p_] := Total[# Log[#] & /@ p];
SliceContourPlot3D[entropy[{p1, p2, p3}], 
 p1 + p2 + p3 == 1, {p1, 0, 1}, {p2, 0, 1}, {p3, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

IE, the following is adapted from ListPlot3D but fails here

```
SliceContourPlot3D[entropy[{p1, p2, p3}], 
 p1 + p2 + p3 == 1, {p1, 0, 1}, {p2, 0, 1}, {p3, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> Specularity[50], 
 Lighting -> {{"Directional", 
    RGBColor[1, .7, .1], {{5, 5, 4}, {5, 5, 0}}}}]
```

(PS: any idea why using `Entropy` instead of `entropy` gives an empty plot?)
This is on 12.1.0 on Macbook Pro 2020

Comment: Do you get the desired result if you use `BaseStyle -> Specularity[White, 5]`  + `PlotTheme ->None`?

Comment: You can use `Entropy` as `Entropy[WeightedData[{1, 2, 3}, {p1, p2, p3}]]`.

Comment: yes, BaseStyle seems to work, I wonder what's the difference from PlotStyle

Comment: `*ContourPlot*`s do not have the option `PlotStyle`; but we inject  styling directives using `BaseStyle`.